# Find by pairs within subdocument

Tags: mongodb

I'm not sure if the question title reads quite right. Anyway a document in my collection looks like this:

```
{
  properties: [
    {name:a, value:w},
    {name:b, value:x},
    {name:c, value:y},
    {name:d, value:z}
  ]
}
```

How can I find documents that qualify this condition: "(Where properties.name = a, properties.value = x) AND (where properties.name = c, properties.value = y)" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the query below.  Note that the order of the elements within the sub-document {name:"b", value:"x"} matters:

```
db.foo.find({properties:{$all:[{name:"b", value:"x"}, {name:"c", value:"y"}]}})
```

Or the below query is even better (order of the sub-document doesn't matter):

```
db.foo.find({properties:{$all:[{$elemMatch:{name:"b", value:"x"}}, {$elemMatch:{name:"c", value:"y"}}]}})
```